# Why has my reputation increased?

Tags: support

My reputation recently increased from around 2,100 when I checked yesterday to 2,935 now. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because of a network-wide change to the reputation system Stack Exchange has made. Questions are now worth +10 rep (before it was +5 rep).

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) for more information from the Stack Exchange team.